# SVGs and PNGs not loading

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-5

I am working on a micro frontend using Webpack.

And I have a problem where all local my SVGs and PNGs are not being loaded by Webpack5 react app. I keep getting 404 when doing that.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone point me out what I am doing wrong?

Here is the folder structuring

```
/public
/src
 /components
   navbar.tsx
   /assets
     Logo.svg
webpack.config.js
```

Here is my Webpack config. I am including the loader for assets, as indicated in the Webpack documentation

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".vue", ".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: "babel-loader" },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "App1",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {},
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

And here is one of the images imported in the Navbar.

**Navbar.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <img src="./assets/Logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the developer tools? Please include exact error messages in your question (copy/paste)

Comment: @phuzi I get a 404 NOT FOUND error, I have attached the image above.

Comment: Don't use a relative path. Move your `assets` folder to the `public` folder then reference your image as `src="/assets/Logo.svg"`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving.

Answer (score -1):

With the app rendered in App.js maybe your url img src should be something like `src='./components/assets/` because it would start from the src folder l? (i know if it's an import it works as expected but here it's a src ..)